# uploading a manuscript tex file for review in springer journal

Tags: errors, pdf, journal

I am trying to submit a manuscript in springer journal. the paper is written in latex. the journal asked to upload .tex file of manuscript and figures separately so i did. but the build pdf is not correct. it returns some strange document with error messages from latex (cant figure out it why).  my question is kindly guide me how to upload .tex manuscript so that the system can build correct pdf.

Comment: Without the error message we can't hope to help here

Comment: the whole pdf is comprised of cover page and then                               "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.4.6) 17 SEP 2016 03:51
entering extended mode
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.14 &
 pdflatex
I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is
simple: Just type `I\&' now. might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable. ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
......blabla

Comment: when latex is compiling the paper correctly. nut submission system is not compiling it.

Comment: in this case, the error message is not enough.  please add a small, compilable example that triggers the error message.  since the error shown is `Missing \begin{document}`, it is very likely that the error occurs in your preamble, maybe even in one of the loaded packages, although that's less likely than in one of your own definitions.

Comment: Please read the instructions on the journal's website carefully. I had the same problem with one of the Elsevier journals and when I double checked the instructions, I could find the solution. Of course most of journals accept the PDF files and the tex files are required only for further publishing procedure.

Answer (score 2):

What solved my problem is that I also uploaded all Springer's files: svjour3.cls, svglov3.clo and spmpsci_unsrt.bst that I got from them in their latex folder.

Answer (score 1):

Usually such errors appear because the LaTeX manuscript file has figures and library files with paths.
One should always submit a LaTeX manuscript after removing the path in the figures names, such as:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{C:\mypaper\figs\foo.pdf}
\caption{a test figure}
\end{figure}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{..\figs\foo.pdf}
\caption{a test figure}
\end{figure}
```

these are both wrong.

For submission, it should be reformatted to the following form:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{foo.pdf}
\caption{a test figure}
\end{figure}
```

Similary, the bibliography section should not be:

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{..\library.bib} or \bibliography{c:\mypaper\library.bib}
```

It should be:

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{library.bib}
```

As a rule of thumb, no paths in the file names whether relative or absolute.

Style files, on the other hand, are usually not required to be submitted at all.

Comment: Welcome, backslashes in path names are wrong anyway.

Comment: file extensions can be usually neglected.